# Error: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting the following error:

> Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

I am trying to send an array of files to the backend where I need to specify 3 items in the https request.

I have this:

```
  const handleImageReader = async (type, image, otherInfo) => {
    const imageData = new FormData();
    const imageReader = new FileReader();
    imageReader.onloadend = async function() {
      imageData.append('type', type);
      imageData.append('otherInfo', otherInfo);
      imageData.append('image', image, image.name);

      await CompanyInfoFilesAPICall(imageData);
    };

    if (image) {
      imageReader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  };

  const handleRequest = () => {
     const productsOrServicesImages = startupFourthStepForm.products_or_services;
     if (has(startupFourthStepForm.products_or_services, 'photos_videos')) {
      for (let i = 0; i < productsOrServicesImages.length; i += 1) {
        handleImageReader('STARTUP_PROFILE_IMAGE', productsOrServicesImages[i], i);
      }
  };
```

If I remove the third parameter (`otherInfo`) everything goes well. That parameter is just the index. And it is a requirement but it says is not the type 'Blob'.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: You use `async/await` syntax in wrong way.

Comment: Hi, @hindmost it doesn't matter for now. My issue is another one. But thanks.

Comment: What is `productsOrServicesImages[i]` what do you have if you console log that, what you have if use `typeof image` or `image.constructor.name`? Maybe it's a string or based64 encoded data, if so you need to convert that to blob, search google or SO how to do that.

Comment: Hi @jcubic the only problem I am having right now, is with the parameter `otherInfo` which is the `index`.

Comment: I don't think so you don't use that parameter in FileReader it's probably from `imageReader.readAsDataURL(image);` as error shows. So you image is not Blob nor file from input element. you need to convert that to blob or file instance.

Comment: Quick test, replace `imageReader.onloadend` with empty function and you should have same error, there will be no `otherInfo` in the code.

Comment: If `startupFourthStepForm.products_or_services` is file input then you need to use `files[i]` to get proper file object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications